# React-Native. Sorting Data In FireBase Not Working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of activities stored in firebase from a react-native client structured as such:

```
users
  CPJGUWKgDEOQG1WTDhxvXMXkgWm2
    activities
      -L8jrsvjH6oqdTiSIIQM
        endTime: 
        1522273600578
        startTime: 
        1522271400000
      -L8js52vrkAiYJWra04P
        endTime: 
        1522482300000
        startTime: 
        11522280700000
```

And I am trying to sort it based on descending order based on start time.

The first approach i tried was to sort it on the server side as a set of rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
      "activities": {
        ".indexOn": "startTime"
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

The second approach was trying to order it when querying from the client-side:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/activities`).orderByChild('startTime')
```

Instead of just:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/activities`)
```

Non of these options worked at all, I was returned the exact same list as if I had not done this procedure. What am I doing wrong and how can I receive a list of items ordered by a certain property.